# Webapp Migration

Tags: java, web-services, jsf, netbeans

I'm trying to redo a webapp that was designed some 3 years ago.  It uses these com.sun.rave.web classes that from what I've been able to piece together is part of some Netbeans garbage called Visual Web JSF.  There doesn't seem to be a jar for this, and I'm not sure if it would work in IntelliJ even if there was.  To be honest, having a web application dependent on IDE is just stupid.  Does anyone know a way to get around this, or do I have to build this webapp from scratch?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I agree that tying oneself to a particular web design tool is ... ummm ... a bit short-sighted.

One migration path that is often mentioned is ICEFaces; e.g.

- ["Woodstock to ICEFaces migration"](http://www.icefaces.org/main/ajax-java/woodstock-migration.iface)
- ["NetBeans Visual Web Pack Dead, What a Shame"](http://www.ensode.net/roller/dheffelfinger/entry/netbeans_visual_web_pack_dead)

Comment: ICEFaces looks almost like what I want.  Still looks like there will be alot of changes to the individual jsp files though, and the ones that I'm looking at are 1000 lines long and full of butt ugly, generated code.  I'm not all the experienced with JSF in the first place, so I may just stick to solid Spring and go with Spring Web Flow to handle all this stuff.  Might take awhile but building something new and learning is alot easier than redoing something horrible bit by bit and learning.